# Create a second configurable bar with a module

Tags: module, hook, prestashop

Hello I'm trying to add a second configurable bar (*being able to transplant blocks in it and manipulate it with the live editor*) at the start of the page header.

My module registers the hook:

```
public function install() {
    return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('displayTopMost');
}

public function hookDisplayTopMost($params) {
    return $html = $this->display(__FILE__, 'blocktopmost.tpl');;
}
```

I modified `blockcurrencies.php` to add compatibility with my hook:

```
public function hookDisplayTopMost($params) {
    return $this->hookDisplayTop($params);
}
```

I transplanted the currencies block to my hook.

And finally added the `{hook h='displayTopMost'}` in the right place in my template files.

I still have no clue what to type in `blocktopmost.tpl` to invoke the Currencies block that's transplanted into my custom hook.

Also, am I tackling the problem with the right tools?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is the currency block not displaying in the templates where you call `{hook h='displayTopMost'}`?

Comment: In `header.tpl` before the `displayNav` html block. It doesn't show the currency block but it renders the `blocktopmost.tpl` as intended.

Comment: Hmm... well if you have only one currency in store or catalog mode, the currency block will not show. The only other thing I can think of is to register your hook in `blockcurrencies.php` as well.